# Check if an array element exists

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a complex array of nested hashes. I'm trying to test whether a specific element is empty.

The following methods return NoMethodError on the console:  .`empty?`, `.nil?`, `.blank?`

Here is the array (formatted somewhat)

```
{
     "query"   =>"ominous",
     "sourceLanguage"   =>"en",
     "targetLanguage"   =>"en",
     "primaries"   =>   [
        {
           "type"         =>"headword",
           "terms"         =>         [
              {
                 "type"               =>"text",
                 "text"               =>"om·i·nous",
                 "language"               =>"en",
                 "labels"               =>               [
                    {
                       "text"                     =>"Adjective",
                       "title"                     =>"Part-of-speech"
                    }
                 ]
              },
              {
                 "type"               =>"phonetic",
                 "text"               =>"/ˈämənəs/",
                 "language"               =>"und"
              },
              {
                 "type"               =>"sound",
                 "text"               =>"http://www.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/ominous.mp3",
                 "language"               =>"und"
              }
           ],
           "entries"         =>         [
              {
                 "type"               =>"meaning",
                 "terms"               =>               [
                    {
                       "type"                     =>"text",
                       "text"                     =>"Giving the impression that something bad or unpleasant is going to happen; threatening; inauspicious",
                       "language"                     =>"en"
                    }
                 ],
                 "entries"               =>               [
                    {
                       "type"                     =>"example",
                       "terms"                     =>                     [
                          {
                             "type"                           =>"text",
                             "text"                           =>"there were x3cemx3eominousx3c/emx3e dark clouds gathering overhead",
                             "language"                           =>"en"
                          }
                       ]
                    }
                 ]
              }
           ]
        }
     ]
  }
```

So for example, I know that a specific element is empty (or doesn't exist), however, when using any of the above three methods to test this, I'm getting a NoMethodError.

Examples:

```
2.1.0 :034 > result["primaries"][0]["entries"][0]["terms"][0]["text"]
=> "Giving the impression that something bad or unpleasant is going to happen; threatening; inauspicious" 

2.1.0 :035 > result["primaries"][0]["entries"][0]["terms"][0]["text"].empty?
=> false
```

Now, I know the next element is empty (doesn't exist), so I'm using:

```
2.1.0 :036 > result["primaries"][0]["entries"][1]["terms"][0]["text"].empty?
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
  from (irb):36
  from /home/kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
  from /home/kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
  from /home/kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
  from script/rails:6:in `require'
  from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I've also seen the `.include?` or `.in?` methods for checking literal values, but I want to check if the element exists with any data.

Comment: So the value can either be a Hash, Array, or String, and you are looking for any place where these are empty?

Comment: In order for us to be able to test our responses, it would be great if you can provide something we can load (the array above seems broken). Do you mind providing the yaml conversion of your array? `require 'yaml'` and `puts yourarray.to_yaml` . Share the output with us =)

Comment: I don't mean to be critical, but for your own sake it may be time to re-evaluate your data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
result["primaries"][0]["entries"][0]["terms"][0]["text"] rescue false
```

Comment: I'm trying to use an if statement like 'if [element] rescue false == false' but am getting syntax errors closing the evaluation

Comment: @Kyle.Belanger enclose the whole expression in parentheses: `if (result["primaries"][0]["entries"][0]["terms"][0]["text"] rescue false)`

Comment: Is `rescue` a *little* slow for normal programs? Maybe he can use `throw`/`catch` for that?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting a NoMethodError is that `result["primaries"][0]["entries"][1]` is nil, there is only one element in the array `result["primaries"][0]["entries"]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
def recursive(arr)
   arr.is_a?(Array) ? arr.map{|x|recursive(x)} : arr
end
```

your array huge and I'm lazy to debug this output.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you may use `defined?`:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
puts :defined if defined? arr2 # puts nothing because arr2 doesn't exist
puts :defined if defined? arr  # "defined"
```